How to share parameters between scenarios in k6 [Dependent scenarios]
I faced with situation where i must generate token using UI and pass it thru to api. But can't send parameter from one scenario to another one. To be more precise I cant send more than one time. Let me explain more detailed:
Goal is: run browser() scenario to get TOKEN, store it somewhere, use in in api() scenario.
Options file:
{
  "scenarios": {
    "browser": {
      "executor": "per-vu-iterations",
      "iterations": 1,
      "vus": 1,
      "maxDuration": "45s",
      "exec": "browser",
      "gracefulStop": "0s",
      "options": {
        "browser": {
          "type": "chromium"
        }
      }
    },
    "api": {
      "startTime": "45s",
      "executor": "constant-vus",
      "exec": "api",
      "vus": 3,
      "duration": "170s",
      "tags": {
        "test_run_id": "ScenarioName"
      }
    }
  }

Test class:
import {sleep} from "k6";
import DatadogMetricsSender from "../DatadogMetricsSender.js";
import locationSteps from "./utils/locations-utils.js";
import apiStepsLocation from "./utils/api-utils.js";
import performLoginAndPullBearerToken from "../UIAuthenticationClient.js";

const testConfig = JSON.parse(open("./test-options/api_options.json"));
export const options = testConfig;
let httpReqParams = { headers: {} };

export async function browser() {
  try {
    const token = await performLoginAndPullBearerToken();
    httpReqParams.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching token:", error);
  }
}
export function api() {
  sleep(1);
  console.log('token' + httpReqParams)
}

the log is:
token{}
token{}
token{<generated topic appears>}

So, actual result is receiving token but only for one VU, but we expect browser() will generate token one time which will be used for all VUs in API.

Why do you need a browser to obtain an authentication token?

App specification.

Your comment seems to be incomplete

We have integration with Azure to get Microsoft users on AWS. It a reason why we should add login and get token from browser cache.  And it works for first run.

Generally, that's what the setup lifecycle method is for. I'm not sure if the browser API is supported in the setup function though (but I don't think you need a UI browser to obtain a token, performing the HTTP requests should be sufficient).
Note that variables defined in the init context are not shared by VUs; each VU gets its own init context and its own, separate set of variables. Thus, it's currently impossible to share data between VUs without additional services.
export function setup() {
  try {
    const token = performLoginAndPullBearerToken();
    return { token: token };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching token:", error);
  }
}

export function api(setupData) {
  const token = setupData.token;
  console.log('token' + token)
}

You might be able to leverage the experimental redis module to store the tokens in a remote Redis cluster from one scenario and then query the same Redis cluster in the other scenario.

It is not possible to get token in other way. And unfortunately setup() cant run browser steps :(

@TarasHoruk I don't understand why it wouldn't be possible? Does your app/service not use an oauth2 flow to obtain the token?

We have integration with Azure to get Microsoft users on AWS. It a reason why we should add login and get token from browser cache.  And it works for first run.
Simply, it is not clear oauth2
